# How to get AWS credentials for Jenkins + ECR + Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, pipeline, credentials, amazon-ecr

I am currently building Jenkins + ECR CI/CD.

Here's pipeline code.

```
docker.withRegistry(
   'https://ID.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', 
   'ecr:eu-west-1:86c8f5ec-1ce1-4e94-80c2-18e23bbd724a') {
```

My Question is How can I get ECR login credential?

The login credential in the above code is 'ecr:eu-west-1:86c8f5ec-1ce1-4e94-80c2-18e23bbd724a'.

My reference documentation is https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecr/

Answer (score 0):

Install AWS Pipeline Plugin in Jenkins,
Then you can create an aws credential from Manage Jenkins - Manage credentials

Answer (score 0):

Open a freestyle job. You can find "Credentials" under git or docker. Choose one to click add. The default credential provider is jenkins. Click it and choose "AWS credential". Fill amazon access key ID and access key and submit.

Go to "Manage Jenkins" and then "Manage Credentials". You can find credential id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).